# MVC 4 change membership database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I created an mvc 4 application code first application, the membership tables aren't being stored on the .\SQLEXPRESS database, I changed the name of the connection string name to my dbcontext which is EntitySets and also changed the InitializeMembershipAttribute class with the EntitySet context but they still aren't being stored? Thanks for the help!!

DbContext

```
 public class EntitySets: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserStats> UserStats {get;set;}
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

AccountModel

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
    : base("EntitySets")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

InitializeMembership

```
 public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
    private static object _initializerLock = new object();
    private static bool _isInitialized;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
    }

    private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<EntitySets>(null);

            try
            {
                using (var context = new EntitySets())
                {
                    if (!context.Database.Exists())
                    {
                        // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                    }
                }

                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("EntitySets", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Connection String

```
 <add name="EntitySets"  connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Fitness_Friend.Web.Models.EntitySets;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You must manually register the MembershipProvider using aspnet_regsql tool.

See codeproject for an step by step configuration of this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89029/Using-SQL-Membership-with-ASP-NET-application

Comment: Asp.net MVC 4 uses simple membership by default, it no longer needs the full SQL Membership Package.

Comment: I just want to add the simple membership tables to my existing code first database

Comment: To achieve that you must implement the membershipprovider and membershipuser to work with EF or use the EF membership http://efmembership.codeplex.com/

Comment: no, simple membership is built in when using the ASP.Net MVC 4 template.  the problem is, in VS 2012, the membership will use (localdb) while the Entity Framework Entities are being stored in .\sqlexpress.  I'm working on spinning up a default site right now to refresh my mind on the changes that need to be made

Comment: I got it working, the changes were correct I just needed to make a new connection to the database in .\SQLEXPRESS, thanks for the replys